# Get same employeeid who belongs to different deptno at a particular interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to list each employee who belongs more than one dept for a given period of time.

| Empid | Dept | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 10 | 10/02/2022 |
| 002 | 20 | 10/02/2022 |
| 003 | 30 | 10/02/2022 |
| 001 | 20 | 10/02/2022 |
| 002 | 30 | 10/02/2022 |
| 001 | 10 | 11/02/2022 |
| 002 | 20 | 11/02/2022 |
| 003 | 30 | 11/02/2022 |
| 001 | 20 | 11/02/2022 |
| 002 | 30 | 11/02/2022 |

From the above source. I need a Output

| empid | Dept |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 10 |
| 001 | 20 |
| 002 | 20 |
| 002 | 30 |
| 003 | 30 |

I have written something like below. But it is not giving proper result.

```
select count(employeeid), dept
from dbo.employee
where date between '2022-02-10' and '2022-02-11'
group by dept
having count(employeeid) > 1
```

Could someone help me to get the desired output

Comment: It's not the [first time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the user has been reminded of the feature [accept feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), @Stu . Considering their question score, however, I suspect that they are on the verge of a question ban; none of their undeleted questions have a positive score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    EmpId, Dept
FROM dbo.employee
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-02-10' AND '2022-02-11'
GROUP BY EmpId, Dept
```

Comment: This is a question/comment, not an answer.

Comment: In a stage we are converting yyyy-mm-dd format. It is not an issue